# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.createReadStream is not a function. Error at the time of image uploading to ipfs( pinata)

Tags: reactjs, ipfs, nft

I was trying to upload image to pinata ipfs cloud from my frontend app of react js. But it shows me error:Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.createReadStream is not a function. .

Here is my code snippet:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');

const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const key = process.env.REACT_APP_PINATA_KEY;
const secret = process.env.REACT_APP_PINATA_SECRET;

export const pinFileToIPFS = async (filePath) => {
const url = "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS";
//we gather a local file for this example, but any valid readStream source will work here.
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file',fs.createReadStream(filePath));

return axios.post(url,
    data,
    {
        maxContentLength: 'Infinity', //this is needed to prevent axios from erroring out with large files
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
            'pinata_api_key': key,
            'pinata_secret_api_key': secret
        }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      //handle response here
      return {
        success: true,
        pinataUrl: "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/" + response.data.IpfsHash
    };
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      //handle error here
      console.log(error)
        return {
            success: false,
            message: error.message,
        }
  });
};
```

How to fix it Or Is there any way of doing this rather than using 'fs'?

Answer (score 0):

1. 'fs' package has been deemed as malicious software, from [github security placeholder](https://github.com/npm/security-holder) page: "This package contained malicious code and was removed from the registry by the npm security team...". I wouldn't recommend using it.
2. The error message is specifying `(TypeError): fs.createReadStream is not a function.`
3. While doing research, I found `fs-extra` npm package is a good replacement for `fs`.

With fs-extra, you can use the `readJson` (one of many [methods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)) method executing it with a `callback`, `promises`, or `async/await` e.g.:

```js
const fse = require('fs-extra');

...

try {
    const fileObject = await fse.readJson(filePath);
    data.append('file', fileObject);
    console.log(fileObject);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}

...
```

If this is doesn't work, based on this [node.js example](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/) attempt the following:

1. Create a variable with the createReadStream method:

```
 // This line opens the file as a readable stream
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
```

2. Use the following as intended to retrieve the response and catch any errors

```
  // This will wait until we know the readable stream is actually valid before piping
  readStream.on('open', function () {
    // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
    readStream.pipe(res);
    // in your case:
    data.append('file', res);
  });

  // This catches any errors that happen while creating the readable stream (usually invalid names)
  readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    res.end(err);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But after fixing according to you it shows :  TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
(anonymous function)
node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:139
  136 |   }
  137 | 
  138 |   // This ensures `util.promisify` works as it does for native `fs.read`.
> 139 |   if (Object.setPrototypeOf) Object.setPrototypeOf(read, fs$read)
      | ^  140 |   return read
  141 | })(fs.read)
  142 | .......

Comment: _'fs' package has been deemed as malicious software_ -- The `fs` package _on npm_ is malicious, yes, but `require('fs')` *ALWAYS* imports the `fs` module that's _built-in to Node.js_. By the way, `fs-extras` just adds a few things to `fs`, so if you use `fs-extras`, you're using `fs`.

Comment: @user17242583 I was not fully aware of it and just noticed the warning messages about the malicious software and though it wouldn't be a good idea but you bring up a good point.
arefin: I will update my answer to the best of my knowledge resorting back to "fs".

Comment: Guys. Use `import … from "node:fs/promises";`.